# Spring constructor autowiring and initializing other field

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I having a Spring class, where I am autowiring a service using constructor, plus in the same constructor I am intializing other field of the same class.

```
@Component
class Converter {
  private TestService testService;
  private Interger otherFields;
  @Autowired
  public Converter(TestService testService) {
     this.testService = testService;
     this.otherFields = new Integer(10);
  }
}
```

My Functionality is working fine, but is it a good practice?, would `@Autowired` annotation have any impact on `otherFields` intialization process

Comment: No why would it? It only indicates that a dependency of the type `TestService` needs to be passed into the constructor, for the class it still is just a call to to constructor.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks I had the same thought, just I need to confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't. Back in the xml days, when you want to pass on an argument to a constructor, you mentioned your ref bean for the constructor arg. This just means that you must have a constructor that takes the specified bean type as an argument. It doesn't really matter what you add in the constructor, as long as you are creating a valid object through the constructor (though this is just normal java programming and nothing to do with Spring).

Auto-wiring is just an easy way to create your object with the necessary dependencies and your code is still your code.

Answer (score 1):

No.

When Spring is instantiating your class it will locate the constructor annotated with `@Autowired`, collect the beans that corresponds to the arguments the constructor takes and then invoke it with those beans as arguments.

It will then scan through all fields and methods in your class and inject beans into any fields that are annotate with `@Autowired`. It will not touch methods or fields that are not annotated.